# Only two values are being returned? Why is my high value not returning and defaulting?

Tags: java

I need to put my numbers into ascending/descending order. Shouldn't really matter after my println. Only 2 of my 3 entered values return in my print statement. Any help where I am going wrong?

"Write an application that asks a user to enter three integers. Display them in ascending and descending order."

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class AscendingAndDescending {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scanner1.nextInt();
        int b = scanner1.nextInt();
        int c = scanner1.nextInt();

        int high = 0;
        int med = 0;
        int low =0;

        if (a>b&&b<c){
            low = b;
        } else if(a<b&&b<c){
            med = b;
        } else if(a>b&&b>c){
            med = b;
        } else if(a<b&&b>c){
            high = b;
        }

        if (b>a&&a<c){
            low = a;
        } else if(b<a&&a<c){
            med = a;
        } else if(a>b&&c>a){
            med = a;
        } else if(b<a&&a>c){
            high = a;
        }

        if (a>c&&c<b){
            low = b;
        } else if(a<c&&c<b){
            med = b;
        } else if(c>a&&b>c){
            med = b;
        } else if(a<c&&c>b){
            high = b;
        }
        System.out.println(high +" " + med +" "+ low);
        System.out.println(high +" " + med +" "+ low);
    }
}
```

***EDIT*** [Newest output as of 10:35 PM 10/06/2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fel0G.png)

[image]

Comment: Simply replace all the or `||` with and `&&` and you should be good ;)

Comment: It will help if you edit the question and tell us exactly what you put in, and exactly what you get out. And what is wrong with what you get out.

Comment: Updated my post. Now have the most recent code, but for some reason not getting a consistent output.

Comment: Some odd chance you guys see this, I am in the clear. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The check for `a` is wrong:

```
} else if(b<a&&a<c){
    med = a;
} else if(a>b&&c>a){
    med = a;
```

Both conditions are the same: they both check `b < a < c`. None of them checks whether `b > a > c`.

You made a mistake when copying it from the `b`-case. Same error in the `c`-check as well.

Lesson learned: [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Instead, write a helper method and call it once for each number.